# Is there a way to do mapping of all subsets of a set of size n to access particular subset elements in < O(n) time

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, memory, data-structures

I have set A of n elements, size of each element is considerable.
I have map M of size k, where k is just indices 0..k and value is elements of one of the subset.

As you can see I need to store k subsets in the map. value of k and n could be in million. So the memory for map is blowing up. 
As many elements in these k subsets would be common. Its like wasting lot of memory in redundancy.

Is there a way to map a particular subset and map it to key in M, so that program takes space for only n elements.
Or any other better way to optimize this memory?

Comment: From the nature of the question, I'm a bit in doubt if it is the right place for *this* site, possibly [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) would have been more appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

The theory says that there are 2^N possible subsets of a given set. It also means that each subset can be uniquely identified by a number between 0 to 2^N - 1. For example let's assume that our set A has 3 elements X, Y, Z, then:

1. Id=0 (binary 000), {}
2. Id=1 (binary 001), {Z}
3. Id=2 (binary 010), {Y}
4. Id=3 (binary 011), {Y, Z}
5. Id=4 (binary 100), {X}
6. Id=5 (binary 101), {X, Z}
7. Id=6 (binary 110), {X, Y}
8. Id=7 (binary 111), {X, Y, Z}

It means that in your dictionary you do not have to store the entire subset as a value but only an identifier of this subset. The only requirements is that you need to be able to change a given identifier into a subset.

In the example above I did it in a very simple way. Imagine yourself that you have a bit array of length N where N is a length of a set. This array represents a subset. Each bit in this array represents one element in a set. If a given bit is set to 1 it means that a given element is in a subset.

This bit array we can treat as a binary number. And each binary number can be easily translated into a decimal number (your id of a subset) and vice-versa.

Returning to our example. The bit array as below:

|X|Y|Z|

|1|0|1|

Denotes that X and Z are in a subset. Identifier of this subset is 5 (binary 101).

**Update 1**

If you really have to deal with millions of elements it means that in the apraoch described above you cannot use standard types `like` int or `long` as identifiers. They cannot store very big values like 2^1_000_000. Instead, you will have to use something like `BigInteger` from C# or Java.

**Update 2**

1 million elements = 
1 million bits in a bit array =
125_000 bytes =
122 kilobytes per a subset identifier.

The question is how big are your elements. This solution is useful (for 1 million elements) if **122 kb < average size of elements in a subset.**

Comment: Oh, that's interesting (+1). Would even allow to add new elements (getting new, higher ids), other changes, though, would break the approach...

Comment: *'Update 1'*: The infamous `std::vector<bool>` might be just the right choice for this purpose, especially, as we most likely won't need the numerical value itself; instead, the index `operator[]` might be useful to determine if a specific element is contained in the set; I assume iterators and range-based for-loop being quite useful as well.

Comment: *'Update 2':* If there are quite a number of *equal* subsets, sharing these just as in my answer (with all its disadvantages as well, though) could help sparing some memory.

Comment: Drawback of this approach: One potentially needs large map entries even for small subsets, if these contain elements with high ids (worst case: subset only containing element with highest id...). Doesn't disqualify the approach in any way, just to be kept in mind when deciding which approach is the most suitable.

Comment: Optimisation possibility: As we don't need to store the most significant zeros, assigning most commonly used elements the smallest ids (if that's possible at all with reasonable effort) will help reduce memory usage as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<Element> allElements;
std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<Element>::iterator>>; //(!)
```

This approach is fine, if you create the set of n elements once and don't ever modify it again (the set itself, you *can* modify the elements inside).

Changing the set during run-time might invalidate the iterators, though; if you only `push_back` new elements, you could store indices into the set instead (*edit:* for the two fore-mentioned use cases, have a look at [Michał Komorowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460363/micha%c5%82-komorowski)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57196289/1312382), too, it appears superior to me, if the subsets are really large as well, but inferior on smaller ones, as you potentially have to store many zeros if an element with large id is contained in the subset). If you remove elements in between, subsequent indices would change, then you need another data structure of which the iterators remain stable even on modifications; such data structures are e. g. `std::list` or `std::set` (actually `std::map` as well, but that is less suitable for the given purpose unless you want some separate, explicit mapping into the set of n elements as well; note that the two unordered variants of set and map don't give that guarantee of stable iterators):

```
std::list<Element> allElements;
std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::list<Element>::iterator>>;
```

Only thing that you still have to pay attention for is not removing any elements from the `std::list` that are yet referred to by any of the subsets.

If there are many equal subsets, you might (especially as the sets apparently are large) additionally spare some memory by sharing these:

```
std::list<Element> allElements;
std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::list<Element>::iterator>>>;
```

An issue with this approach are modifications of the subsets, they'd be visible to all maps sharing the same subset – which might even be desirable, but if not, you'll need to address the issue in some appropriate manner.